# React native keyboard's height changes entire view

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, jsx

My layout with two inputs and a button works well without the keyboard. But as soon as I clicked the input box the keyboard appears and changes the height of the screen. Then things align wrong . I already tried using keyboard avoiding view. But the error is still there.

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  Button,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
} from 'react-native';
import {  Formik} from 'formik'; 
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class Demo extends Component {

    render(){

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior= "position , padding , height">
      <View style={styles.container}> 
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>Profile settings</Text> 
        <View style={styles.card}>
              <Formik
                initialValues={{
                  name: '',
                  mobile: '',
                }}
                onSubmit={(values) => {
                  console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
                }}>
                {(props) => (
                  <View>
                    <TextInput
                      placeholder={'name'}
                      onChangeText={props.handleChange('name')}
                      value={props.values.name}
                      style={styles.cardTextSmall}
                    />

                    <TextInput
                      placeholder={'email'}
                      onChangeText={props.handleChange('mobile')}
                      value={props.values.mobile}
                      style={styles.cardTextSmall}
                    />

                    <Button 
                    title={'submit'}
                    />
                  </View>
                )}
              </Formik>

              <View style={styles.centerButton}></View>
            </View>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
}; 
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({  
  centerButton: {
    top: '1%',
    alignContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  titleText: {
    fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
    fontSize: 30,
    position: 'relative',
    left: '7%',
    top: 72,
  },

  cardContent: {
    paddingHorizontal: '10%',
    marginHorizontal: 10,
  },

  cardTextLarge: {
    paddingTop: '15%',
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#A6A6A6',
    fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
  },

  cardTextSmall: {
    borderBottomColor: 'black',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
    fontSize: 18,
    color: '#404040',
  },

  cardTextModule: {
    paddingLeft: '15%',
    paddingTop: '2%',
    fontFamily: 'Segoe UI',
    fontSize: 18,
    width: '100%',
    color: '#404040',
  },

  card: {
    borderRadius: 6,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    shadowOffset: {width: 1, height: 1},
    marginHorizontal: 4,
    left: '6.5%',
    top: '19%',
    height: '78%',
    width: '85%',
    margin: 'auto',
    position: 'relative',
    zIndex: -1,
  },
});

export default Demo;
```

[image]

I'm a beginner here. If you could please give me some explanation. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you have used KeyboardAvoidingView with one of the behavior as padding. So whenever you click on TextInput it adds bottom padding to the view and view moves towards the top.

If you don't want it to happen, use View tag instead of KeyboardAvoidingView.

Comment: I've already tried that. I've given position as relative and top property as a percentage. That's why I put KeyboardAvoidingView

Comment: For me that still happens even if i don't use KeyboardAvoidingView

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me.
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

with

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

in your android/app/src/main/Android.Manifest.xml

Restart the project after making these changes